# TitleLabel is broken when you put a UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`. Custom cell contains `UIButton` and `UILabel`.

Here I observe that `UILabel` text is change as I expected but `UIButton` text is not changing.

When I scroll out the button outside of the screen, change the label of UIButton.

Why it is not working? I have use Xcode 6 and use below code.

---

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "customTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customTableViewCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    customTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.button.titleLabel.text = @"Label does not change immediately";
    cell.label.text = @"change label";
    return cell;
}
```

customeTableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface customTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the [`UIButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uibutton_class/index.html) class has multiple states (Normal, Selected, Highlighted, Disabled). When you change the text property of it's internal `UILabel` (`textLabel` property of `UIButton`), it's property is overriden by `setState` function, which is called when table is loaded.

To change text in the label of a button you need to call `setTitle:forState:` method. Here is your code fixed to work:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    customTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.button setTitle:@"Now it works" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.label.text = @"change label";
    return cell;
}
```

For the sake of completion, you can also use `setAttributedTitle:forState:` method with `NSAttributedString`, so you can actually set your own specifically formatted string as a title.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
[cell.button setTitle:@"MyNewTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```